# jQuery parsererror on simple JSON returned from Django

Tags: django, json, jquery

I'm doing a pretty simple thing here, making a POST request to Django from jQuery, and I'm getting a strange error for a pretty simple scenario. I have the following view function:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template as dto

def do_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return dto(request, "path/to/template.json", {
            'success': False,
            'cause': None
        }, mimetype="text/json")
```

Here's my template:

```
{ success : {{success|lower}}{% if cause %}, cause : {{cause}}{% endif %} }
```

...and here's my jQuery:

```
$.ajax("/login/", { type: "POST",
    data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("login response: " + data);
    },
    error: function(data, stats, error) {
        console.log("login fault: " + data + ", " + 
                stats + ", " + error);
    }
});
```

Pretty simple, right? Here's what I get in the console:

```
login fault: [object Object], parsererror, SyntaxError: Unexpected token s
```

What's going wrong here? If I don't set the `mimetype` on my render method, then everything works fine. The problem is, I'd like to return JSON without having to force jQuery to reparse it. Can anyone spot my mistake here? I can't seem to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON is not valid. You need quotation marks around the identifiers, so `"success"` instead of `success` and `"cause"` instead of `cause`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I didn't know this was required, as in JS `{ success: true }` is the same as `{ 'success': true }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json

def do_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': False, 'cause': None}), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Super helpful, thanks. That makes things a little easier and means I don't have to write a template for it.